# Snapping elements / conditional layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

Sorry for the extremely bad title, I have no other idea what to call this question. What I'm trying to do is this: have a `RelativeLayout` which has two children:

1. one with `layout_centerInParent="true"`
2. one with `layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

However, when the device is in landscape mode, element (1) appears slightly *over* or *under* element (2). But, element (1) has enough space above it to appear **above** element (2). How could I make the layout so that if the screen is too small to center element (1) and make both elements **not** overlap, then align element (1) **above** (as in `layout_above`) element (2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work to give you a layout where the `text1` item fills the available space above `text2`, and is centered vertically and horizontally in that space;  and `text2` is on the bottom, centered horizontally.

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:text="Centered" 
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bottom"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

The important parts are `android:layout_weight`, combined with `android:gravity`.

Comment: That's what I finally went with. Changed the `RelativeLayout` to a `LinearLayout` and used the weight/gravity combo you suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Alright here's a leftfield suggestion that might work if your element (1) isn't too resource intensive.

Have two versions of element (1), the first with `layout_centerInParent="true"` and the second with `layout_above="@id\element2"`. Default them both to `android:visibility="invisible"`. In your onCreate Post a Runnable that inspects the Y dimension of both elements, and sets `View.VISIBLE` on the element with the smallest value.

Comment: For this solution I'd have to use `.postDelayed()` (`.post()` doesn't work), which seems very ugly to me. Still, +1 for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

New idea:

This is another idea that's sort of a workaround in that it's not very elegant, but it's very simple. Put element (1) in its own < LinearLayout > configured like so:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" // More on this line below
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/element2"
    android:gravity="center">
```

That linear layout will always span from the top of screen to just above element (2), and since its gravity is "center", element (1) will always be in the middle of whatever space is available for it. Note: The line `android:layout_height="..."` is required, but doesn't seem to actually do anything. Whether it's fill_parent or wrap_content, its height is overridden by the lines anchoring its top to the ParentTop and its bottom to element(2). However, not having the line makes it crash with a Runtime exception.

---

Original, not very good idea:

Another less-than-ideal solution is to use two layout files. Put the portrait layout xml in your layout folder and the landscape layout in a new folder called layout-land. Android then automatically selects the right one based on the orientation of the phone. I think you could use `layout-port`, but putting the portrait one in just `layout` makes sure it knows which one to use by default.

Comment: Nice idea, but even if the device is in landscape mode it might have enough space to fit element (1) in the center. And if it's a really big device it might actually look awkward.

Comment: Thanks for the new idea, will try it a bit later